# Isolineal mapping of a square to a disk

Tags: geometry

I want to find any mapping of a square onto a disk where a translating straight line set is sent to a rotating semi-circles set keeping lengths the same.

The following is my attempt. It can be seen through a Mathematica  output for a circle diameter $d$  where *lengths but not angles* are conserved.

The $u$ parameter slant straight line has a length of $\pi/2$ which equals boundary length of a semi-circle. The translations parallel to $u$ lines are mapped as rotations around the origin. So also for $v$.

```
d = 1; 
ParametricPlot[d/(2 Sqrt[2]) {u + v, u - v}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, Pi},   Mesh -> {7, 7}, PlotStyle -> {Yellow}]     
ParametricPlot[  d Sin[u] {Cos[u - v], Sin[u - v]}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},   Mesh -> {15, 15}, PlotStyle -> { Yellow}]
```

EDIT1:

The mapping occurs in a NASA Technical Note by Hans U Schuerch, Astro Research Corpn, Santa Barbara, CA in sixties.

To explain what I mean by iso-lineal, it can be recalled that every differential element in a Chebychev net described by Sine-Gordon is conserved in the 3D hyperbolic geometry model.

[image: Iso-lineal mapping]

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Only one region is shaded in the preimage but two are shaded in the image. The text says "Edge AbC stretches to semi-circles": is that one or two semicircles? And the image diagram implies AbC maps to the diameter of the left circle. Please clarify the mapping.

Comment: I have recast the question almost entirely, removed the drawing hopefully for better clarity. The comment above is not about the present post.